# How can I pass credentials in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I've got 2 options to pass creds to terraform provider:

1. Setup ENV variables like `FOO_PROVIDER_USERNAME` & `FOO_PROVIDER_PASSWORD`. Update: and read them from ENV in a source code of a provider so there's no username / password vars in `*.tf` files.
2. Set it explicitly in a provider:

```
provider "foocloud" {
  username = "admin@foocloud.org"
  password = "coolpass"
}
```

Shall I pick #1 or #2? My concern about #2 is that those username / password might be saved to a state file which is a security concern.

Comment: Best practice is to use environment variables.

Comment: I've had similar question couple of weeks ago regarding this. We've used the #1 option that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: this is typically for managing secrets in resources:

A few weeks ago, I came across this great article by Yevgeniy Brikman:

https://blog.gruntwork.io/a-comprehensive-guide-to-managing-secrets-in-your-terraform-code-1d586955ace1

Out of the two options you mention, go with option 1 (like you said, option 2 will write them to the state file) but you should set the variables as sensitive.

Example:

```
# main.tf

resource "foocloud" {
  name     = "foobar"
  
  username = var.username
  password = var.password
}

# variables.tf

variable "username" {
  description = "foobar"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "password" {
  description = "foobar"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

# command line or in text file

export TF_VAR_username=foo
export TF_VAR_password=bar
```

EDIT: in the case of authentication to cloud providers such as AWS you can use the credentials files among other options, as explained here:

https://blog.gruntwork.io/authenticating-to-aws-with-the-credentials-file-d16c0fbcbf9e

Comment: Interesting, I updated the question to include more details for #1. It looks like your approach combines them all.

Comment: That answers it for where the provider or resource doesn't automatically have support for using environment variables without the `TF_VAR_` prefix but doesn't say why you would do that when the provider does support native environment variables, largely following the underlying SDK (eg the AWS provider). For that case it's nearly always preferable to take the first option and not define the variables at all because then it can also utilitise the entire chain of providing credentials (eg EC2 IMDS, `~/.aws/credentials`, AWS SSO or AWS-Vault)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR agreed, I edited the answer to clear things up